# Updating thousands of features in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, markers

I am a new to using OpenLayers and I am trying to properly show thousands (~5000) of features (ol.geom.Point) in a layer. I have a slider that represents years (`year`), and when I move the slider the size of the points change reflecting the difference `year-ye`, where `ye` is the year field of the mark. The problem is that all the points flash when I do this, and this is ugly and very distracting. You can check it working [here](https://luis.impa.br/conservacao/megafaunaextinction.html).

How can I prevent this flashing?

This is how I do it: first, I loop over all marks in a Database, I clear all the marks in the layer, and then in a loop I add the marks with this function:

```
function addmarkHuman(ye,lat,lon) {
var feature = new ol.Feature({
 geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([lon, lat])),
 year: ye,
});
var size = Math.floor(10 + (ye-year)/1000);
feature.setStyle([ new ol.style.Style({ image: new ol.style.Icon({ src:
  'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="' + size + '" height="' + size + '" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="' + size/2 + '" cy="' + size/2 + '" r="' + size/2 + '" fill="rgb(153, 204, 255)" /></svg>'
}) }) ]);

humanLayerSource.addFeature(feature);
};
```

I then changed the strategy: instead of clearing the marks, I just update their style. Unfortunately, the result is the same: all flash like if they were removed and recreated.

Maybe I can tell the map to not update until I process all the marks, kind of "flush at the end". Or maybe I can reuse the same `Icon` changing the size?

I tried updating the style instead of deleting and recreating without luck: the old marks still flash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are recalculating features creating an array followed by

```
source.clear();
source.addFeatures(featureArray);
```

would be better as it is a single add event

But better still do not set a style on the features, use a style function on the layer

```
var layerStyle =  new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: ?? // data url for max size image
  })
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: featuresArray
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    if (feature.get('year') >= sliderYear) {
      scale = ?? // calculate size for feature divided by max size
      layerStyle.getImage().setScale(scale);
      return layerStyle
    }
  }
})
```

Then whenever your slider or checkbox is updated call `layer.changed();`

Comment: Excellent!! I implemented both things, the array + style function. Worked as a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: BTW, I tried with `source: new ol.source.Vector({features: featuresArray})`, and then after moving the slider, clearing and populating `featuresArray`, and calling `layer.changed()` but it showed no marks. I ended up doing as before with `source: new ol.source.Vector()`, and then `layer.getSource().clear(); layer.getSource().addFeatures(featuresArray);` and it worked. I did not call `layer.changed()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It should work, see https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-scale-forked-g0z2pz?file=/main.js which is single feature https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-scale.html adapted to show multiple features.  Also there should be no need to clear and add features, if they are not needed on the display do not return a style (as in my example if there is too much negative text rotation).